# Is it possible to use a defined variable as a kind of 'data-content' for the data attribute selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, attributes, selector

I would like to know if it is possible to use a defined variable as a kind of "data-content" for the data attribute selector in jQuery.

Lets say I have a variable called "imageNumber" which consists of integers:

`var imageNumber = 1;`

And I have a row of preview images with a background-image attribute and a data attribute called 'data-image-number="1"', 'data-image-number="2"' and so on:

```
<div style="background-image:url(example1.jpg);" data-image-number="1"></div>
```

I look for a way to set the background-image of a kind of "display"-div based on another div selected via a variable(imageNumber) in jQuery.

$("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number='imageNumber']").css("background-image"));

```
$("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number='imageNumber']").css("background-image"));
```

At this moment I look for every case via if clauses:

```
    if ( imageNumber == 1 )
    {
        $("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number='1']").css("background-image"));
    }
    if ( imageNumber == 2 )
    {
        $("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number='2']").css("background-image"));
    }
```

I need this to have a Timer which updates the background-image of the "display_div" via the variable "imageNumber", because the Images are fading one by one in the display and users shall have the option to click on a preview image, set the variable "imageNumber" to the position in the fading-row and the fading-row shall just work its way again.

I fear/guess there is no syntax for this problem and I have to solve it another way or use the if-clauses am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use string concatenation:

```
$("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number=" + imageNumber + "]").css("background-image"));
```

or with quotes if there's any chance that what you're concatenating may have spaces or such:

```
$("#display_div").css("background-image", $("div[data-image-number='" + imageNumber + "']").css("background-image"));
```

---

In ES6 (ECMAScript 2015), you could also use a template string:

```
$("#display_div").css("background-image", $(`div[data-image-number='${imageNumber}']`).css("background-image"));
```

...but most browsers don't support them yet.

Comment: Somehow know i feel a bit ashamed :D Thank you very much!